# How to compute shortest distances of points and curve in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

Let's say I have a fitted curve in gnuplot (or simply sin(x) function) and file with data - points nearby the function. How to compute the distance of points from the curve and write them to the file with data in gnuplot? Is it possible to implement easily sum of squares in gnuplot? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to mix two different concepts.  If the curve was fitted to the points then the component term in the sum-of-squares uses the difference in y values. I.e. for a point [xi, yi] the term is (func(xi) - yi)**2.

But this is not the same thing as "distance of the point from the curve", since the nearest point on the curve may be at some different x value.  The answer to that question in general requires calculus and is not something that gnuplot is designed to help you with, although if you work out the relevant equation you could use gnuplot's "fit" to find the minimum by approximation rather than by solving the differential equation analytically.

**To plot the residuals after fitting**
Assume data points [xi, yi] in columns 1 and 2 of file "data".
Assume fit(x) is the function you got from fitting. Then you can plot the residual for each point:

```
plot 'data' using 1:( (fit($1)-$2)**2 ) with linespoints
```

Comment: Thank you very much and when I do the fit, is somewhere any information which points suits worse?

Comment: It is not stored anywhere during the fit itself. But you could take the equation for the fit and the same data again to show the residual for each point. See amended answer.